# How to use vcpkg to install (manage) my own library?

Tags: windows, macos, cmake, lib, vcpkg

I'm using vcpkg for a little while in a Windows project with a few external libraries, and internal ones too. Now project is going to be ported to macOS and vcpkg seems to help a lot on getting those external libraries on macOS.

Can I manage my own libraries with vcpkg?

Comment: Exactly the same as on windows? Just pass other target triplet and adjust your internal libraries portfiles so that they can be built on macos.

Comment: Sorry, could you be a bit more verbose? Pass other target triplet where?

Comment: In command line when you invoke cmake (`cmake -D VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-osx-whatever`) or in `cacheVariables` of your preset for macOS in `CMakePresets.json`. https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/manifests.md#cmake-integration

Answer (score 4):

> Can I manage my own libraries with vcpkg?

Yes take a look at [overlay-ports](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/2022.04.12/docs/specifications/ports-overlay.md)

You basically write a manifest (vcpkg.json) and a `portfile.cmake` for your library and have it in an overlay or custom registry.

[New MSDN Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/concepts/overlay-ports)

Comment: Link is broken (404).

Comment: Fixed by linking back to former commit. Unfortunately the current official docs in the vcpkg-docs repo does not yet contain a section about overlay-ports.